# 20% of requests to google docs api return 401 unauthorized

Tags: google-drive-api

We have a background job that syncs a little over a thousand google drive articles to our server. The job syncs all articles everyday. When this happens approx 20 percent of the requests fail with a 401 response. It is not specific to any files somedays a file will get a 200 others it will get a 401, generally files towards the end fail.

This has been a pain to debug as it will only happen on our production server only when syncing all. The same articles with the same keys will pass even on production when synced individually.

I have tried so far:

- checking googles rate limits.(user and app) both are within limits.
- delaying time between requests.
- retry with delay.

Were using ruby and the google-api-client gem.
Also V2 of their api.

At this point I'm currently out of options, and looking for ideas or wondering if someone else has had a similar issue.

**Updates/ Answer comment questions:**

- On the 2nd try they still fail same error 401.
- With each file we are doing 3 requests; the metadata, a plain text and 1 more. Total of 3 requests per file.
- Our total file count is roughly ~1300 files x 3 requests is a lot but again we checked that we are within rate limits and were getting a 401 not the rate limit error.
- None of the requests are batched, were still within rate limit I did not see the immediate advantage.

Comment: i've had similar stuff happen in the past, decided it was a bunch of bullshit, and basically did ```try{stuff();}catch(ex){if(401){/*sometimes we get a completely bogus 401, so lets try again just to be sure.*/stuff();}}``` - while that just works around the root cause rather than fixing the root cause, it worked great

Comment: @hanshenrik I should have mentioned we do retry with a delay currently 2 seconds. what was yours set to?

Comment: Does your request work in your second try @ChrisCPO? How many files are you interacting with your process? How many request are you actually sending to Google's side?

Comment: @Raserhin I will edit question to answer your question.

Comment: @ChrisCPO: 3900 request for one day is no too much, but 3900 concurrent request could exhausted the resources. So optimal spread-up concurrent request will could help, in consider to resources also to avoid any bottleneck of network traffic, and troughput. Otherwise fragmenting download mechanism is an advantage.

Comment: @LennartManfred I see what your saying and as far as I can tell that is true for a normal api. Googles rate limits are in the millions even billions for some its crazy, why would I not get a rate limit error https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/handle-errors. Also we tried a 2 second delay between every file instance so a second delay between every 3 requests.

Comment: @ChrisCPO: then how long time the connection keep alive from local server to google api server? Is it some limitation for that case?

Comment: @LennartManfred Maybe? The connection is usually pretty quick were not talking about massive files, at most 10 pages of content, there are some with a good bit of images though, worth taking a look. Would that not be a timeout error? thanks for your help.

Comment: @ChrisCPO: You are welcome. It sounds the requests been serialized, but I dont know how much parallel requests for each. But the remote server could assume that as any attach or another unpretty kind of terms of service violation. So will be better if you read the terms carefully. But If its okay, I think the requests could be scheduled for more than seconds, maybe in minutes or more, and make sure to close the connection for each.

Comment: @ChrisCPO I tried to reproduce this but I got no luck, maybe your best solution is to reach directly to google support through [this link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en). They will have the right tools to help you debug your problem.